# Integral using Simpson's Rule

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp, numerical-methods

As an answer to this problem:

> **Exercise 1.29**
>
> Simpson's Rule is a
>   more accurate method of numerical
>   integration than the method
>   illustrated above. Using Simpson's
>   Rule, the integral of a function f
>   between a and b is approximated as
>    (h / 3) * (y_0 + 4y_1 + 2y_2 + 4y_3 + 2y_4 + ... + 2y_(n-2) + 4y_(n-1) + y_n
>
> where h = (b - a)/n, for some even
>   integer n, and yk = f(a + kh).
>   (Increasing n increases the accuracy
>   of the approximation.) Define a
>   procedure that takes as arguments f,
>   a, b, and n and returns the value of
>   the integral, computed using Simpson's
>   Rule. Use your procedure to integrate
>   cube between 0 and 1 (with n = 100 and
>   n = 1000), and compare the results to
>   those of the integral procedure shown
>   above.

I wrote the following solution:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (define (iter a result)
    (if (> a b) 
        result
        (iter (next a) (+ (term a) result)))
    ) (iter a 0))

(define (simpsons-rule f a b n)
  (let ((h (/ (- b a) n)))
    (define (y_k k) (f (+ a (* k h))))
    (define (even n) (= (remainder n 2) 0))
    (define (term n) (* (if (even n) 2.0 4.0) (y_k n)))
    (define (next n) (+ n 1))
    (* (/ h 3.0) (+ (y_k 0.0) (sum term 0.0 next (- n 1.0)) (y_k n)))))

(define (cube x) (* x x x))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `sum`, make sure you start with 1 (and not 0).  Otherwise, you get an error of + 2 y_0 h / 3.  In case of `(simpsons-rule cube 1 2 1000)`, this error is 0.000666....

Another way to rewrite the series is to group even and odd terms together, excluding the first and last terms.

(h / 3) * (y_0 + y_n + 4 * (y_1 + y_3 + ... + y_n-1) + 2 * (y_2 + y_4 + ... + y_n-2))

This gives us another possible implementation:

```
(define (simpsons-rule f a b n)
  (define h (/ (- b a) n))
  (define (y-k k) (f (+ a (* k h))))
  (define (next n) (+ n 2))
  (* (/ h 3.0) (+ (y-k 0) (y-k n) (* 4 (sum y-k 1 next (- n 1))) (* 2 (sum y-k 2 next (- n 2))))))
```